# iOS app freeze for ~0.5 second on swipe back gesture

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to develop our mobile app.  When I open new screen like this:

```
   Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute/CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewScreen(....),
          ));
```

and I swipe back using swipe gesture, the UI is not clickable for like 0.5 - 1 seconds afterwards.  It makes the app feel unresponsive and slow.  What is causing this "freezing"?  Is something eating the touch events?

Similar issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48225

Comment: You are not providing enough code but i suggest you to check the app performance with devtool to identifying if there is a performance problem.

Comment: Does this happen every time, or only the first few times after launching?

Comment: I tried investigating this issue and found out this is due to IgnorePointer. Please refer to my reply in GitHub, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48225#issuecomment-757817127

Comment: after search this issue, i  find out this problem also cause flutter 1.23 version.but using this,
https://pub.dev/packages/fluro, navigation work fine

Comment: Experimenting this issue in every single Flutter app I know, not only mine. Makes the app look cheap and still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried investigating this issue using the sample code provided by @edwardez and found out that this is due to...

File: routes.dart
Class: _ModalScopeState
Function: build(...)
Lines:

```
AnimatedBuilder(
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! userGestureInProgressNotifier becomes true
    animation: widget.route.navigator?.userGestureInProgressNotifier ?? ValueNotifier<bool>(false),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        final bool ignoreEvents = _shouldIgnoreFocusRequest;
        focusScopeNode.canRequestFocus = !ignoreEvents;
        return IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: false,//ignoreEvents,  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< Tried setting it to FALSE, resolves the issue.
            child: child,
        );
    },
    child: child,
),
```

Setting the `IgnorePointer`'s `ignoring` property to false retains the First screen's animation and resolves the issue.

When I tried setting the `userGestureInProgressNotifier` to always return to false, and reverting my changes in IgnorePointer...

File: navigator.dart
Function: set _userGesturesInProgress
Lines:

```
set _userGesturesInProgress(int value) {
    _userGesturesInProgressCount = value;
    //userGestureInProgressNotifier.value = _userGesturesInProgress > 0; // <<<<<< Commented
}
```

This also resolves the issue but there's no animation for the First screen. (same as pressing back button in AppBar).

My Flutter doctor...

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/rickkystiannelim/Documents/sdk/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (5 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/rickkystiannelim/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)         // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< IDE used
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

 
[✓] Connected device (1 available)                    
    • ASUS Z012DA (mobile) • G8AZCY00Z1714K5 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) // <<<<<< Device used
```